# Is it posible to view content of a Realm DataBase where the app is on a iPad Side-Loaded?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm-database

I have a app that displays data from a Realm database. but when I run the app it only shows the word "hello". Because of that, I want to check what the content of the DataBase is.

If I run the app and I print out the following line:

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
```

then I get a file URL, which I can open by writing in the terminal:

```
open //theURLPrintedToTheConsul
```

But the terminal doesn't find the file that the print line prints out

is it posible to view the DataBse content when the app is side-loaded on a physical device? if yes, how?

thanks!

Benji

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write your realm data file using [Realm Studio](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/).

Comment: Also if the app is sideLoaded on an iPad? Bc the terminal doesnt find the file the consul prints out

Comment: No but it works when the app is side loaded on a simulator.